# Import a directory of dbf files to sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to import `.dbf` files using for each container in ssis. But I keep getting errors to map the files and other errors.

Here is what did.

1. Use for each container.
2. Use a data flow task in the container.
3. Use oledb source for Visual Foxpro (or jet ) and set expended properties as dbase iv and connection string as variable from expressions.
4. Use another variable for SQL Server table name, removing `.dbf` extension.
5. Use a sql oledb destination and set its table as table, view or variable name. Set the variable to created one in step 4.

As the SQL Server table is not there already how to create and import dynamically. There is lot of dbfs so looking for dynamic creation of the same and import.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the FoxPro environment (ideally, Visual FoxPro 9, SP2), you can use the Sql Server Upizing Wizard to push the tables and data into a Sql Server database. You will need to add each dbf to a FoxPro DBC container if it is not already in a DBC.

You can download the latest version of the tool here: https://vfpx.codeplex.com/releases/view/10224

You can read this article about using the tool: http://www.codemag.com/article/0703052

I have personally used this tool, so I know it works, and it's pretty easy to use.